# I cannot bind rows in R

Tags: r, data-binding, data-analysis, bind-rows

I'm just a beginner in R and I'm having trouble in a capstone project on the google analytics data certification. I have to analyze data from a fictional company from the last 12 months (I've chosen June22 to May 23), and after creating dataframes for each months, I'm trying to bind_rows to create a single database for the whole year. But I'm encountering this issue:

```
> rides_last_year <- bind_rows(june_2022, july_2022, august_2022, 
+ september_2022, october_2022, november_2022, december_2022, january_2023, february_2023, march_2023, 
+ april_2023, may_2023)
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$started_at` <datetime<UTC>> and `..2$started_at` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If you need more info I'll gladly provide it.

PS: june_2022 and so on are the dataframes created for this project.

Got no idea to solve it, right now, do I have to change something from my data?

Comment: This means that your dataframes have a column `started_at`, which is of type `datetime` in some dataframes and is `character` in others. The easiest way round it is perhaps to convert them all to character, do the `bind_rows`, and then try to create the dates (if you need to) from the combined dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would put everything in a list, use `map_dfr` to cast everything to the same type and simultaneously bind the rows, then type convert on the back end.

```r
library(tidyverse)

list(june_2022, july_2022, august_2022, september_2022, october_2022, 
     november_2022, december_2022, january_2023, february_2023, 
     march_2023, april_2023, may_2023) |>
  map_dfr(~mutate(across(everything(), as.character))) |>
  type_convert()
```

If you know that `started_at` is the only problem variable, you could just cast that one variable and save yourself some time. I imagine that you'll probably have problems with `ended_at` as well.

Comment: Finally I used the glimpse function to know in which format were each column, in fact, onone month, the started_at and ended_at where on a different format, so I use the mutate(). Thanks!